# Creating a Struct from Text File

Tags: c, struct

i've been starting this project that requires taking data from a text file and inputting it into a struct. I've researched online and tried running codes like this:

```
 // C program for reading
// struct from a file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// struct person with 3 fields
struct person
{
    int id;
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
};

// Driver program
int main ()
{
    FILE *infile;
    struct person input;
    
    // Open person.dat for reading
    infile = fopen ("person.txt", "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    
    // read file contents till end of file
    while(fread(&input, sizeof(struct person), 1, infile))
        printf ("id = %d name = %s %s\n", input.id,
                                          input.fname, 
                                          input.lname);
    // close file
    fclose (infile);

    return 0;
}
```

But the output is this:

```
id = 1025533033 name =  521 name = Bill Smith
id = 432 name = W`û@vÇ th
id = 432 name = W`û@vÇ
id = 543976553 name = Gates
id = 888 name = Steve Musk
id = 96`û@vÇ = Steve Musk
id = 96`û@vÇ
```

when the text file contains this:

```
id = 521 name = Bill Smith
id = 432 name = Will Gates
id = 888 name = Steve Musk
id = 968 name = Elon Jobs
```

P.S. The file name is set correctly to "person.txt"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot read *text files* with `fread()`. `fread()` is for binary files; `fgets()` is for text files.

Comment: Read the file as text and parse the contents of each line e.g. using some scanf variant.

Comment: @pmg doesn't `fgets()` read just a single string?

Comment: @Pinguiz `fgets()` reads a **single line** (provided it has enough size to store it), including the final `'\n'`. If you want to call that line a "single string", then *yes, `fgets()` reads a single string.*

Comment: "A single string" is what you have in `"id = 521 name = Bill Smith"`. There is no way you can use `fread` to extract the data from the identifiers. It's unclear why you even expect any library function to realise that `name = ` introduces two names for two data fields.